# Connecting to ActiveMQ form grails

Tags: grails, groovy, activemq-classic

I am trying to connect to a remote ActiveMQ server from my Grails app.
But I get this error:

```
ERROR failover.FailoverTransport  - Failed to connect to transport after: 5 attempt(s)
could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'queue' - retrying in 5000 ms.
Cause: The JMS connection has failed: connect timed out
```

Transport configuration of the ActievMQ server is :

```
   <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

Resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
jmsConnectionFactory(SingleConnectionFactory) {
    targetConnectionFactory = { ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf ->
        brokerURL = "failover:(tcp://brokerIpAddress:61616?connectionTimeout=5000)?maxReconnectDelay=5000&startupMaxReconnectAttempts=5"
    }
}}
```

Comment: does it work with other clients?  aka: no firewall issue etc?

Comment: It works when i try it from localhost and i checked that port is open and i don't think that firewall is the issue

Comment: try with <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://Ipaddress:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/> sometimes binding doesnt work well

Comment: Sorry for very late replay  but it was an network problem the activeMQ server was not  accessible for that machine. Its all good now and its working with conf that i posted originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was an network problem the activeMQ server was not accessible for that machine. Its all good now and its working with conf that i posted originally.